# Project Summary Web Part not available

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, project-summary-web-part

I am a site owner of a SharePoint Sever 2013 SharePoint site. I have all permissions except for: *Create Subsites* and *Use Self-Service Site Creation*. I am not a site collection administrator.

I want to start using the **Project Summary web part** so I've turned on the **SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features** Site Feature via *Site Settings > Manage site features*. On the main page of the site, the Project Summary web part was automatically inserted, but I didn't want it there, I wanted it on another page.

**** *Edit* The **Project Functionality** site feature is also turned on. ****

I deleted the one on the main page and went to to the other and completed the following steps:

- edited the page
- Insert > Web Part
- navigated to Content Rollup
- project summary web part is not there.

[image]

As far as I know, I have everything enabled that I should have to have the web part available.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the answer. I didn't read the web pages as thoroughly as I should have. The project summary web part that is addable to pages is only available in **SharePoint project sites** and **not team sites**. The project summary is still available on team site home pages, but is not addable to any other pages on a team site.

Sources:

- *"added by default to the Project Site Templates"* - http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/09/the-new-timeline-and-project-summary-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013/
- *"By default, it is included on the Home page for a **project site**. It can also be added to any other site that includes a task list."* - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-tasks-and-events-in-the-Project-Summary-web-part-03ce0b76-3e4e-4991-ad73-d745c889a2f2
- *"Project Summary – web-part that is included in the SharePoint 2013 Project Site"* - http://wiki.plexhosted.com/kb/Microsoft_SharePoint_2013:Project_Summary_Web_Part
- *"great new addition to SharePoint Project Sites"* - http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/07/11/how-to-use-the-project-summary-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You have to activate **Project Functionality** feature too at Manage Site feature to use Project Summary Web Part.

So navigate to **Manage Site Features >> Project Functionality >> Activate**

And you are done.

Check [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4385f293-4dc5-40e0-9c57-231e5ee1b2db/project-summary-web-part-not-available?forum=sharepointgeneral) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for that, I already had it turned on. Turning it on and off will place the Project Summary web part on and off the main page for a site, but I still can't see the web part to be added to a different page.

Comment: I have done the same thing and I am able to add the project summary web part at any page. It seems that I have to dig more into your issue.